# Python: Formatting file paths with a variable filename

Tags: python

I used r' in front of the string so that Python doesn't treat the backslashes as escape sequences.

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\file.xlsx', index = False) #exporting to excelfile named "file.xlsx"
```

However, this time I need the filename to be a variable instead.
I usually format it by using F-string but I can't combine the r' and f' together. It doesn't work

```
df.to_excel(r'f'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\{filename}.xlsx'', index = False)
```

How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect, try `rf'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\{filename}.xlsx'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are wrong. You can use it like this.

```
df.to_excel(rf'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\{filename}.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using either [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module in case you are working with paths and want your project to be compatible with different OS.

For pathlib, you can use the following snippet. Note that the forward slashes will be automatically converted in the correct kind of slash for the current OS.

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("C:/Users/A/Desktop/Data/")
file_name = 'myname.xlsx'
file_path = data_folder / file_name

df.to_excel(file_path, index = False)
```

The answer to your current question would be using string concatenation. Something like this:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\' + f'{filename}.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to place each within quote marks- 1 set will do:

```
fr'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Data\{filename}.xlsx'
```